# Use black version of site navigation

Tags: html, css

I want to use beautifull page navigation. When I downloaded below version:
http://codeb.it/resmenu/

I found file index.htm. In that file navigation is white. I tried use css style from orginal page (foundation.css) but this file have the same class like boostrap.

Please help me, I want to use this navigation (http://codeb.it/resmenu/) in black color.

I know, maybe it is easy question but please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you read all the documentation from the page you provided?

At the end of it, there is a snippet which shows you how to style the navigation bar:

```
.responsive_menu select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* This is black */
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I read documentation and i do this but IT'S NOT WORKING!!!

I sent my code. Maybe I did sth wrong. Please help me. Why it's not working?

http://www.filedropper.com/navmenu

Comment: You don't have to send us the code in a zip file... put it in the question..

Comment: This is the code:
http://textuploader.com/feju